# Email trigger bringing null asset

Tags: trigger, email

I have this trigger:

```
trigger Email_Pesquisa_Mercado_account on Account (after update) {

Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, Name, (Select Id,Name from Assets where Quantity>0) from Account Where Id in : Trigger.New]);

for(Account Ac : Trigger.New){
  if(ac.separador__c == 'pesquisa'){
   String AssetName;
   if(accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets.size() > 0){
    for(Asset obj : accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets){
        if(obj.name != null){
     AssetName = AssetName + ', ' + '"'+obj.Name+'"';
        }
        }
    }
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[]{};   
                toAddresses.add(ac.PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

            mail.setreplyto('naoresponda@cp7.com.br');

            mail.setSubject('Pesquisa');
            mail.setHtmlBody('Olá, '+ac.FirstName+' '+ac.LastName+'<p>'+AssetName+'</p>');

            Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
        }
    }
}
}
```

I receive the email like this:

```
Olá, Xxx Xxx
null, "AMPLIAÇÃO", "FOTO 20X30CM", "DVD", "AR - SUPER VIP"
```

Why I am receiving a null asset?
What should I do?

Comment: It looks like you are setting AssetName in an If statement.  If you are looking at an account with no assets, then AssetName will be null and therefore would show up as null in your email.

Comment: What should I do to make my trigger not look for accounts that doesn't have assets?

Comment: Adjusted the code in an answer below.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I got it!

```
for(Asset obj : accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets){
   if(obj.name != null){
if(AssetName==null){
AssetName = obj.Name;
}
else{
     AssetName = AssetName + ', ' + '"'+obj.Name+'"';
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to ensure that you are not constructing an email for an account that does not have assets.  To do this, add the lines indicated and delete the lines indicated

```
trigger Email_Pesquisa_Mercado_account on Account (after update) {

    Map<Id,Account> accountMap = new Map<Id,Account>([Select Id, Name, (Select Id,Name from Assets where Quantity>0) from Account Where Id in : Trigger.New]);

    for(Account Ac : Trigger.New){

        //ADD THESE 3 LINES
        if(accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets.isEmpty()){
            continue;
        }

        if(ac.separador__c == 'pesquisa'){
            String AssetName;
            if(accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets.size() > 0){  // DELETE THIS LINE
                for(Asset obj : accountMap.get(Ac.Id).Assets){
                    if(obj.name != null){
                        AssetName = AssetName + ', ' + '"'+obj.Name+'"';
                    }
                }
            } //DELETE THIS LINE
            Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
            String[] toAddresses = new String[]{};   
            toAddresses.add(ac.PersonEmail);
            mail.setToAddresses(toAddresses);

            mail.setreplyto('naoresponda@cp7.com.br');

            mail.setSubject('Pesquisa');
            mail.setHtmlBody('Olá, '+ac.FirstName+' '+ac.LastName+'<p>'+AssetName+'</p>');

            Messaging.SendEmail(new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] {mail});
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Didn't work. I am still getting null.